# I dropped out of my masters degree a year ago and am being threatened by my college that they will blacklist me

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application, university, withdraw

I took a masters a couple of years ago and dropped out because my supervisors weren't helpful, were demotivating (told me they could do my research in two months and asked why I hadn't finished mine), and I also didn't have the money to finish it. I called the university when I got the email of my maximum time to finish my research is ending (asking if I'd like to extend) and I confirmed to them I didn't want to continue and they said okay.

So, I thought I paid full previously but apparently I had some debt left over, which they didn't bother telling me the whole year after dropping out.

One of the finance admin called today to tell me to pay $650 in 48 hours, and threatened to blacklist me if I didn't.

I legit dropped out because of money issues and instead of telling me to pay a little bit monthly, they just dropped the bomb on me like that. No, I don't have the money now, so I'm most probably going to be blacklisted.

So my question is, what happens if my university blacklists me? Does that mean I cannot pay after I'm blacklisted and I'm blacklisted forever? Does that mean I can't apply to other (cheaper) universities? I asked the lady just now and she just laughed and say that's up to the university and I shouldn't ask.

Comment: Does your university hold a certification from the state where it operates? and,do you have a formal report of your califications?

Comment: Yes, they are an official university accredited. And do you mean qualitifications? If yes, then yes i do have my degree transcript and certificates etc.

Comment: Ask them for the accounts showing the reason for the debt, and check them. Some time after I completed my PhD the college finance office called me to say I owed some money. After weeks of discussion, it turned out that someone with a name similar, but not identical, to mine had cancelled a check.

Comment: Maybe that's part of the answer, but what does being "blacklisted" by a university even mean? I presume you have no interest going back there again anyway, right?

Comment: @xLeitix: *but what does being "blacklisted" by a university even mean?* It might mean (I'm guessing) that the university will not acknowledge attendance and/or course credits, and will not provide an official transcript. Depending on what the OP does later, this could be very important, of no concern at all, or somewhere between.

Comment: I'll assume that "blacklist" would only mean that you can't take any courses or get any transcripts from that institution. Is that what you mean, or more than that. It is an odd term to use in academia. It would probably have no effect elsewhere.

Comment: Which country you are talking about?

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, i have zero interest to join the faculty in that university again. So i guess the conclusion is that i shouldn't worry so much since it won't actually affect my life? I'm already working and have my degree trnascripts and everything. I have no idea what blacklist is in university terms, the finance lady just told me i would be in 48 hours.

Comment: Did they ask you to repay your scholarship?  My girlfriend is concerned that if I drop out before finishing my Ph.D, I will have to repay the money